# How To Center Text Inside Of A CSS Shape

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to make a homepage for some work and I want to make a nice little button that says 'Home'. However, I am not to the point of implementing the onclick yet so don't worry about that. I tried making the shape that I want.

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "home">Home</div>
```

Again, I am trying to center the text 'Home' inside of the shape so it looks like it is in the middle of it.

Comment: can you add the complete html code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to center it **both horizontally AND veritcally**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using height just use line-height

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "home">Home</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

I think flexbox might help you, check this code:

```css
#home{  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "home">
  <span>Home</span>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display:flex` approach to center the text from top and left.

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">Home</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **line-height** for this which also works fine. Here is an example, i hope it will help you.

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "home">Home</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display table:

```css
#home {
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: table; 
}
p {
  text-align:center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id = "home">
  <p>Home</p>
</div>
```